# How to fix "['Student Name'] not in index"?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, spyder

I'm new in Programming and I'm trying to replace the old dataframe df with a new dataframe, but when I run the code it says KeyError: "['Student Name'] not in index". How can I fix it?

This is my code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Thep18\Desktop\Thep New.xlsx')

print('\n')
df=df[['Height (cm)','Weight (kg)','Allowance per day','Student Name']]
print(df)

And this is my result
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Thep18/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Thep18/.spyder-py3')

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Thep18/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 20, in 
    df=df[['Height (cm)','Weight (kg)','Allowance per day','Student Name']]

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2934, in **getitem**
    raise_missing=True)

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1354, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1161, in _get_listlike_indexer
    raise_missing=raise_missing)

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1252, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError("{} not in index".format(not_found))

KeyError: "['Student Name'] not in index"

runfile('C:/Users/Thep18/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Thep18/.spyder-py3')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Thep18/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Thep18/.spyder-py3')

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Thep18/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 20, in 
    df=df[['Height (cm)','Weight (kg)','Allowance per day','Student Name']]

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2934, in **getitem**
    raise_missing=True)

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1354, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1161, in _get_listlike_indexer
    raise_missing=raise_missing)

File "C:\Users\Thep18\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1252, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError("{} not in index".format(not_found))

KeyError: "['Student Name'] not in index"

Comment: Take a look at how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Sorry, the question is already edited, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It means that 'Student Name' is not a parameter of your dataframe, when you modify the data structure you have to execute the migration of data before calling the parameter because in the database the parameter not exist.

Comment: Sir, can you please elaborate, I'm really new with this programming.